# Lambda Function to Stop RDS-Instances in all Regions Based on a Tag Filter Using Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I have put together this code to stop rds-instances in all aws-regions. Currently, this code stops only instances in my current default region. Is there something that I am missing here?
Tag:
The instances are first filtered by a tag whose Key = ttl and Value = some date
Filter:
The filter returns only instances whose tag value is smaller than today.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
 

current_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
available_regions = boto3.Session().get_available_regions('rds')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for region in available_regions:
        rds = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
        
      # get all instances 
    instances = rds.describe_db_instances()

    stopInstances = []   
    
      # Locate all instances that are tagged for stop based on date.
    for instance in instances["DBInstances"]:
        # Example RDS Instance tags:
        tags = rds.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=instance["DBInstanceArn"])
            
        for tag in tags["TagList"]:

              if tag['Key'] == 'ttl' or tag['Key'] == '' :

                  if tag['Value'] < current_date:

                      stopInstances.append(instance["DBInstanceIdentifier"])
                      rds.stop_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=instance["DBInstanceIdentifier"])    
                    
                      pass

                      pass


      # print  if instances will stop. 
    if len(stopInstances) > 0:
       print ("stopInstances")
    else:
       print ("No rds instances to shutdown.")
```

Comment: Most of your code should be inside of the `for region in available_regions` loop

Comment: which parts? Can you plz point out specifically? Or is it just an indentation issue?

Comment: All of the parts you want to execute against multiple regions

Comment: it throughs out this error:
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the DescribeDBInstances operation: The security token included in the request is invalid",
  "errorType": "ClientError",

Comment: The Problem was with some of the aws regions (asia pacific) where the IAM is not  active by default. You have to activate them or filter them out. If they are not active the describe command of boto3 will not be able to get those regions thus, throwing the error of InvalidClientTokenId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code now works:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

# Get current time in format yyyy-mm-dd
# define boto3 the connection
current_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# get all regions
available_regions = boto3.Session().get_available_regions('rds')
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for region in available_regions:
        rds = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
        

      # Define instances 
        instances = rds.describe_db_instances()

        stopInstances = []   
    

      # Define and locate tags.
        for instance in instances["DBInstances"]:
    
            tags = rds.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=instance["DBInstanceArn"])
            
            for tag in tags["TagList"]:

              if tag['Key'] == 'ttl' or tag['Key'] == '' :

                  if tag['Value'] < current_date:
    # Stop instances matching a tag pattern
                      stopInstances.append(instance["DBInstanceIdentifier"])
                      rds.stop_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=instance["DBInstanceIdentifier"])    
                    
                      pass

                      pass


     # print  all instances that will stop. 
    if len(stopInstances) > 0:
       print ("stopInstances")
    else:
       print ("No rds instances to shutdown.")
```